# Culvert screen design principles

Tags: civil-engineering, water-resources

Culvert inlet trash screens typically consist of a series of oriented bars/flat bars, angled to some lesser or greater extent in the direction of flow.

What motivates this design? why not a mesh or horizontal bars? what determines the angle? what determines the spacing?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Scottish Government](https://www.gov.scot/publications/flood-risk-management-scotland-act-2009-guidance-duties-local-authority/pages/5/).*

If you mean this type of screen then I suspect that the design intent is to allow debris to be swept up the face of the screen by the water current. It also facilitates raking the screen clean by hand from the top (where the wellies can be seen).

A vertical screen (one standing upright rather than sloped) would result in debris being pressed and held on the screen by water pressure. This would quickly result in blockage, water backing up, gradual blockage of the screen all the way to the top and eventual flooding.

The unit in Figure 1 seems to have a design flaw in the horizontal bar half-way up the screen. If I felt that it was required to maintain parallel of the bars I would have welded on stand-offs on the rear of the bars and then run the horizontal bar welded to them. This would give better chance of avoiding a jam.

> What motivates this design?

Simplicity (cost / manufacturability) and effectiveness.

> Why not a mesh or horizontal bars?

Both would snag debris with no self-clearing.

> What determines the angle?

It's probably a compromise.

- Further from vertical gives better self-cleaning.
- Closer to vertical will require less steel, take up less space, require less groundwork and will result in less flexing.

> What determines the spacing?

The size of debris that the culvert can accomodate without risk of clogging.

Comment: @jsotola, no, but I can see how it might be misread. I've improved it, I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From a layman's point of view, one should discover that properly installed screens do not entrap bicycle wheels for normal travel directions. Water can more easily flow over a ninety degree obstacle than a bicycle wheel can drop into and pop out of the slot formed by a poorly placed grid.

That's not to say that there are not improperly installed grids, but those will often be reported and corrected if there is any appreciable bicycle traffic on the surface.

Comment: I think you misread the OP's mind.

Comment: I agree. The photo you've provided clears up the question nicely.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable design consideration in some cases.